\EFI\ubuntu not found
First post here.
I just installed Ubuntu following the tutorial here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview, and I erased Windows 10, so I installed it over the disk. In my mind, it should have been enough, but I had a lot of problems when trying to start it. After a while I "made" it function, but every time I turn on the computer appears a black screen that says: Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\ - Not found It stays like that for a minute or so, and then it opens right in this place https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation in the paragraph that says:

If you select either LVM or ZFS based encryption you will be prompted
to create a Security key that you will need to enter on boot before
logging in with your user credentials.)

I would like to know if I did something wrong with the installation. I am really new in computer terms and technology, however I have searched around and everyone is talking about some grubx64.efi and it has not helped so far (i.e., the commands that I should put on terminal don't even work). I looked in the files, and indeed the folder \EFI\ubuntu\ does not exist. I think it has something to do with the boot, maybe it is opening something strange, but Ubuntu works normally after those 2 minutes of waiting.
I collected the Boot-Info, according to the following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info in the link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2N7KdMHKTN/
Thanks you in advance, and I am sorry if my question is very basic, and am missing something that should be clear.

What Brand/model system? Some only want to boot Windows. You can remove current Windows boot entry in UEFI with efibootmgr and may want to add a "Window" boot entry that boots grub/shim, so system thinks it is booting Windows but really boots Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win See IV for efibootmgr entry.  See man efibootmgr for examples of deleting with sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B where XXXX is entry you want to remove.  You normally cannot see ESP - efi system partition from your install. Only from live installer or change to fsab.

Thanks for the help. I have an Intel Corporation DH67BL, and it appears it only has Windows Boot Manager. In the case of XXXX, which entry should I write?

See man efibootmgr You typically run sudo efibootmgr -v to be sure of number you want to delete. Some only require on digit, others may need all 4.

Once again, thanks for the help. I tried it removing all of them but it did not work out.

If you remove all of then, then you have nothing to boot. You have to restore Ubuntu entry with efibootmgr or totally reinstall grub which will restore an Ubuntu entry.
